# dots in lineChart dont hide DC.js d3-tip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I'm working with a DC.js lineChart, I added a tooltip with d3-tip, but when I activate it, the points in the lineChart do not disappear, as in the image.

[image]

What can I be doing wrong with the d3-tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier for folks to answer your question if you include a reproducible example and the relevant code in your question.

Did you namespace your events? You probably want `mouseover` and `mouseout` to be handled by *both* the line chart and d3.tip.

So using the quick usage d3.tip code,

```
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
```

should probably be

```
  .on('mouseover.tip', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout.tip', tip.hide)
```

This way `dc.lineChart` will not lose its own mouseout events.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/8z15xboq/6/